# Calculating a proper probability density function on piecewise function

Tags: probability, density-function

I need to prove that this equation is a proper probability density function, that is that it's equal to 1.

$$f(x) = 1 - |x|, for -1 \le x \le 1$$

So I tried to compute the integral
$$\int_{-1}^{1}1-|x|dx = \begin{cases}
\int_{0}^{1}1-xdx, & \text{x >= 0} \\
\int_{-1}^{0}1-(-x)dx, & \text{x < 0}
\end{cases}$$

$$=\begin{cases}
[1 - \frac{x^2}{2}]_0^1 \\
[1 + \frac{x^2}{2}]_{-1}^0
\end{cases}$$
$$=\begin{cases}
[(1 - \frac{1^2}{2}) - (1 - \frac{0}{2})] \\
[(1 + \frac{0^2}{2}) - (1 + \frac{-1^2}{2})]
\end{cases}$$
$$=\begin{cases}
[0.5 - 1] \\
[1 - 1.5]
\end{cases}$$
$$=\begin{cases}
-0.5 \\
-0.5
\end{cases}$$

Adding these two answers together I get -1, not 1. What did I do wrong?

Comment: **BTW:** The integral is *not* a piecewise function, it is a sum.$$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,\mathrm d x&=\int_{-1}^0 f(x)\,\mathrm d x+\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]\int_{-1}^1 1-\operatorname{abs}(x)\,\mathrm d x&=\int_{-1}^0 1+x\,\mathrm d x+\int_0^1 1-x\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&={[x+\tfrac 12 x^2]}_{x=-1}^{x=~~~0}+{[x-\tfrac 12x^2]}_{x=0}^{x=1}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An anti-derivative of  $1-x$ is $x-\frac {x^{2}} 2$. You wrote $1-\frac {x^{2}} 2$.

You should get $\int_0^{1}(1-x)dx=\frac 1  2$ and $\int_{-1}^{0}(1-x)dx=\frac 1  2$.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help... the plot of $f(x)$?

[image]